# How to wipe out current browser session memory on page refresh

Tags: javascript, caching, memory-leaks, openlayers

I have been building a large mostly javascript based mapping system using OpenLayers and I have slimmed the initial page load of data on our largest client account down from 400 MB to about 150 - 180 MB by nulling out ajax json returns when done with the data and removing unnecessary html. On the initial page load, the memory monitor in my browser shows a good number down around 150. As I use the site it builds up a bit, which is expected. BUT, if I refresh the page, the browser clings to a bunch of the previous memory and then nearly doubles by the time the refresh is done loading.

I have added onunload="map = null" where "map" is a javascript var to our mapping library. I've added the php lines as such to the header:

```
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");    // Date in the past 
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");  
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");  // HTTP/1.1 
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false); 
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

I've added the meta lines to the header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
```

But I still can't get rid of the resident memory. When I first launch the browser it's using 35MB roughly on loading the blank page. I would have expected that if I refresh the page, the browser should dump the memory of that page (given the lines above) and start over from the 35MB mark.

Does anyone have a solution to this irritating problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What OS are you on? On some/most platforms, processes do not necessarily give up memory they've allocated, even after internal freeing or garbage collection. What browser are you testing with?

Comment: I am using Firefox 3.6.14 on a Mac. But the same happens on Firefox 3.6 and IE 8 on PC as well. It's baffling that given I am telling the browser to NOT cache the data, yet it still is in some way. If it weren't, then it should dump all data from that page that's in memory.

Comment: With your directive, the browser will not cache the data *to disk*. It still caches on memory, and this is not something dictated by the HTML spec, rather it is based on the implementation. So here, memory not freeing up is due to faulty memory management, not cache control. I suppose you could check what is causing the memory to persist? How do you refresh the page?

Comment: This happens on all browsers and at least Windows XP 32, Windows 7 64 and Apple OSX (or whatever is current). It also happens on all websites, even stackoverflow as you can see here: orbitingeden.com/memoryleak.png This behavior makes it very difficult to write a complex, graphic HTML5 website. My website runs about 400MB in memory. After a few refreshes, the browser tab needs to be closed and a new session started. This is not expected behavior and I have strangely not seen any one else addressing this obvious and serious issue!